# Simultaneous work with file word/excel etc

Tags: windows, file-sharing

Beyond windows file sharing is there other way to work with document simultaneously?
In windows file sharing other users see changes only when document have been saved, what i need is for users see changes when other user make any changes to document e.g. type Hello World and other users who has this document open see changes without him having to save it.
Word, Excel, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You've got things like Google Docs and not much else.

For now still the best way is to use plain text format (latex for example) and merge changes by hand.

Comment: Sharepoint....?

Comment: Isn't Sharepoint a check in/out system instead of a live collaboration system? To bad Google Wave bit the dust eh?

Comment: SharePoint 2010 allows for real-time collaboration on the same document by multiple people. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff718249.aspx

Answer (score 0):

check [Alfresco](http://alfresco.com).  It's a document manager that lets you handle complex collaborations, and includes MS-Office integration (via the sharepoint protocol).

Answer (score 0):

In Excel you can "Share Workbook"  then on the Advanced tab select "Automatically Update" under "Update changes."  This will allow multiple people to open and work in the Excel file and update changes every x amount of minutes without waiting for a save.  Also ensure you have Track changes enabled so you can see what changes have been made etc...